# SQLite exception: no such table on Eclipse

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception

I'm trying to copy an existing database located on assets so that I can access its static information, but I'm encountering a "no such table" error.

Logcat (some of it, if needed I'll post more):

```
11-25 01:30:49.863: E/SQLiteLog(627): (1) no such table: myTable
11-25 01:30:49.873: E/DataAdapter(627): getTestData >>android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: myTable (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM myTable
11-25 01:30:49.873: D/AndroidRuntime(627): Shutting down VM
11-25 01:30:49.873: W/dalvikvm(627): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-25 01:30:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 01:30:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(627): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adiel.cookbook/com.adiel.cookbook.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: myTable (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM myTable
11-25 01:30:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-25 01:30:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
```

Database Handler:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
//destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = ""; 
private static String DB_NAME ="CookbookDB";// Database name
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
private final Context mContext;

public DBHandler(Context context) 
{
super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
this.mContext = context;
}   

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
//If database not exists copy it from the assets

boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
if(!mDataBaseExist)
{
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    this.close();
    try 
    {
        //Copy the database from assets
        copyDataBase();
        Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
    } 
    catch (IOException mIOException) 
    {
        throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
    }
}
}

   //  Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/DaName
private boolean checkDataBase()
{
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
    return dbFile.exists();
}




//Copy the database from assets
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
{
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
    {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Comment: Yes I am. Edited so it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

well it is very easy

you have forgotten to write your database name with extension

in your code:

```
private static String DB_NAME ="CookbookDB";// Database name
```

Should be

```
private static String DB_NAME ="CookbookDB.sqlite";// Database name
```

or what is your exact database extension.

Also there is a problem still exist. there is no upgrade method. For example if you publish this app in the future and if want to make update for app. there will be a problem for that. your new datebase can  not seen for who have alredy using your app and try to update.

you should be carefull that